# Put id and content into table td automatically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create table and put id and content into it with Javascript.

Characters covered with '' is char(first or second letter of the months) and n is number that changes while the for loo runs. Also I have to fill ++n value into td class='firstLine'.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/mydiary.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var x = 32;
      var n = 0;
      document.write("<table>");
      for(i = 0; i<x; i++){
        document.write("<tr>");
          document.write("<td class='firstLine'>/*++n value*/</td>");
          document.write("<td id='j'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='f'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='m'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='a'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='ma'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='ju'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='jl'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='au'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='s'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='o'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='n'+n></td>");
          document.write("<td id='d'+n></td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
        n++;
      };
      document.write("</table>");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is your problem. How does this not do what you'd like it to do?

Comment: @Glubus I got an answer! Thanks for asking!

Comment: Glad you got it working, dont forget to close this question by marking the answer as correct by clicking the check sign next to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you're incrementing `n` twice (if that's based on the intent): once at the start of the table with `++n` and another at the end of the table row writing with `n++`. What you need is to simply execute `n++` at the start.

Also, with regards to appending the ID to your `<td>` element, remember that you are simply performing string concatenation, so this will work:

```
document.write("<td id='j"+n+"'></td>");
```

If you are familiar with template literals, the readability is way better:

```
document.write(`<td id="j${n}"></td>`);
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var x = 32;
var n = 0;
document.write("<table>");
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  n++;
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td class='firstLine'>"+n+"</td>");
  document.write("<td id='j"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='f"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='m"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='a"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='ma"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='ju"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='jl"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='au"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='s"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='o"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='n"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("<td id='d"+n+"'></td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
};
document.write("</table>");
```

```css
/** For stylistics only **/
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
```

---

### Optimization note

If you really want to optimise your code, here are a few more tricks:

- Use `document.body.append(...)` instead of using `document.write`, because it will overwrite everything in the body
- As you are constructing a rather large table, it might make sense to make use of the [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) API.

Here is an example of an optimised version of your code:

```js
var x = 32;
var n = 0;

// Create empty table
var table = document.createElement('table');

// Create fragment to hold all the rows
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  n++;
  
  // Create row and an array of months
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  var months = ['j', 'f', 'm', 'a', 'ma', 'ju', 'jl', 'au', 's', 'o', 'n', 'd'];
  
  // Create and Append first cell into row
  var firstCell = document.createElement('td');
  firstCell.classList.add('firstLine');
  firstCell.textContent = n;
  row.appendChild(firstCell);
  
  // Create and Append all months into each row
  months.forEach(function(month) {
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.id = month + n;
    
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });
  
  // Now we are done with the row
  // Append row into the document fragment
  fragment.appendChild(row);
};

// Now the document fragment is ready to use
// Append entire fragment into table element
table.appendChild(fragment);

// Now the table element is ready to use
// Append entire table into body element
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
/** For stylistics only **/
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
```